# Error: The application “NoMachine.app” is not open anymore

Tags: applications, remote-desktop, error

Every once in a while I'm unable to open the [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) client. If I double click, I just get the error:

> The application “NoMachine.app” is not open anymore.

And nothing in the console.

If I try clicking on one of my usual connections using the top, menu-bar icon --- nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using 10.11, check [this out](https://www.nomachine.com/TR10M06094):

> A crash occurs when executing a call to network API on OS X 10.11 El Capitan
>
> Based on the Diagnostic Report, the crash occurred during the discovering of other computers on the network and it's related to a call to network API.
>
> As a temporary solution, disabling the 'Discovering of other computers on the network' in player.cfg helped, but this is not a fix and we cannot exclude that the crash appears again. There can be other situations in which a call to the same API can be executed.
>
> Workaround:
>
> - Edit the player.cfg file in the .nx/config directory under the user's home (~/.nx/config) on the client computer.
> - Set:
>
>   ```
>   <option key="Discover other NoMachine servers in the network" value="false" />
>   ```

The workaround in that page helped me. Some weeks ago they've also sent me a test library fixing the issue (I've reported the problem on their forums). You may get in touch with them or wait for an official fix.

Comment: Thanks!  Naively, I don't see how these issues are connected...  were you getting the same errors as I am in this situation?